# Onesignal device token not fetching

Tags: android, onesignal

I am using Onesignal in my application. For the first time of installation user ID gets null. After a few minutes able to read it. Few devices are not able to fetch the user ID. What could be the issue for those?

`OneSignal.getDeviceState().getUserId()`

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it too early. Make sure to call it once you know a user id will be there (e.g: after successful subscribing to push).

See https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/sdk-reference#getting-user-properties

Comment: Yes I hope I am calling it early. because after some delay time it's working fine. My question is I required in the splash screen. How to get it there? We can't make wait user there

Comment: While a time-delay might work, you should use the subscription observer callback to only check after subscription.